# Marshalling nested collection objects

Tags: collections, jaxb, nested, marshalling

I want to marshal  the Java Class which has the following data members -

```
private List<ArrayList<DataItem>> dataItemGrid;
public List<DataItem> itemList;
```

which refers to `DataItem class Obj` which has the following data members -

```
private Integer objectRefId;
private String type;
private String id;
private String label;
private List<DataItem> subDataItems;
```

when I try generating a schema, the type of `dataItemGrid` is shown as `arraylist` which should be any `element` instead. How do I do it?